# Dict not able to return data from college scorecard API

Tags: python, json, api

So I've been working on a page which displays a school's name, url, city, state, zip, and student size via College Scorecard API but I'm getting tons of errors instead. However, the program is able to read the JSON data just fine. For example, when I run this:

```
key = "key_string_here"
url_base = "https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools/"

# Makes a get request to collegescorecard API

r = requests.get("https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools/? 
school.operating=1&2015.academics.program_available.assoc_or_bachelors=true&
2015.student.size__range=1..&school.degrees_awarded.predominant__range=1..3
&school.degrees_awarded.highest__range=2..4&id=240444&api_key=api_key_here")

school = r.json()
  for item in school:
      url = ("https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools?"
             "school.operating=1&2015.academics.program_available"
             ".assoc_or_bachelors=true&2015.student.size__range=1.."
             "&school.degrees_awarded.predominant__range=1..3"
             "&school.degrees_awarded.highest__range=2..4&id=240444&"
             "api_key="+key+"&fields=school.name, school.school_url,"
             "school.city,school.zip,school.state,2015.student.size")
req = urllib2.Request(url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
response2 = response.read()
json_data=json.loads(response2)
print response2
```

I get the correct data:

```
{"metadata":{"total":1,"page":0,"per_page":20},"results":[{"school.n
ame":"University of Wisconsin-Madison","school.zip":"53706-1380","sc
hool.state":"WI","2015.student.size":29579,"school.school_url":"www.
wisc.edu","school.city":"Madison"}]}
```

However, when I try to parse the JSON data in a dictionary, like this:

```
params = dict(
    school_name="University of Wisconsin-Madison",
    school_url="www.wisc.edu",
    city="Madison",
    state="WI",
    zip="53706-1380",
    size="29579"
)

resp = requests.get(url=url, params=params)
data = resp.json()
print data
```

I get this in response:

```
{u'errors': [{u'input': u'city', u'message': u"The input parameter '
city' is not known in this dataset.", u'error': u'parameter_not_foun
d'}, {u'input': u'state', u'message': u"The input parameter 'state'
is not known in this dataset.", u'error': u'parameter_not_found'}, {
u'input': u'school_url', u'message': u"The input parameter 'school_u
rl' is not known in this dataset.", u'error': u'parameter_not_found'
}, {u'input': u'school_name', u'message': u"The input parameter 'sch
ool_name' is not known in this dataset.", u'error': u'parameter_not_
found'}, {u'input': u'size', u'message': u"The input parameter 'size
' is not known in this dataset.", u'error': u'parameter_not_found'},
 {u'input': u'53706-1380', u'message': u"The provided zipcode, '5370
6-1380', is not valid.", u'parameter': u'zip', u'error': u'zipcode_e
rror'}]}
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this problem?

BONUS: Any suggestions to improve my web page?

In response to chillin:

```
vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant/scripts$ python school_data.py
  File "school_data.py", line 29
    "school_url"="www.wisc.edu",
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

Edit II:

```
  File "school_data.py", line 28
    school_url: "www.wisc.edu",
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Edit III:

```
vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant/scripts$ python school_data.py
  File "school_data.py", line 28
    "school.school_url"="www.wisc.edu",
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

Comment: In your first example (which provides you with correct data), the parameter is of the form `school.name`, but is  `school_name` in the dict you pass to `params`. The two are not semantically equivalent, maybe this is the problem?

Comment: I tried "school.name" as the variable name on the dictionary, but after running the program, received an error which states "school" (or "name". I tried both. Didn't work.) is not defined.

Comment: I think it is because it thinks you have an object called `school` and it thinks you are trying to access some method/attribute of it called `name`. Are you able to wrap the dictionary key in quotes and pass it as a string? i.e. `params = {"school.name" : "University of Wisconsin-Madison", "school.url" : "www.wisc.edu"}` (this dictionary is not complete, you will need to fill in remaining parameters).

Comment: Yes, I believe I tried that and it didn't work either. I've asked the same question on Reddit and I've got a suggestion, so I may give that a shot. In any other case, I read the college scorecard documentation and "school" is the category and one of it's attributes is called "name".

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and I received "Keyword can't be an expression".

Comment: Any chance you could include the code that generated that message in the question as an edit? Sounds like a reserved word is being used as an expression/variable name.

Comment: I made the edit on the OP. :)

Comment: This might not fix the error, but seems like the `=` should be `:` if you are creating the dictionary between a pair of `{}`. Also, I personally think you should be putting `"school.school_url"` as the key, not just `"school_url"`, so that it matches the first request (which you know to be working).

Comment: I tried ":" and got invalid syntax. For "school.school_url", I received the "keyword can't be an expression" error.

Comment: If you post all of the script that is giving you that message, it would help. I mean the script, not just the error message. Thanks

Comment: Done. Btw, thanks for your help man.

Comment: I guess I wasn't making myself clear enough. I wanted to see the Python code you'd written, not just the error message. Anyway, I have posted something as an answer. Try it. If it doesn't work, let me know. I should be around for a bit and will reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, written on mobile, but I think this should be the same as what you have in your first request. If I was you, I would copy the code below to a new .py file and then run it. That way, if it raises an error, you know something is wrong with my code (and not some other part of your code). Hope it works or gets you closer to a solution.

```
import requests

key = "replace me with your API key"
url_base = "https://api.data.gov/ed/collegescorecard/v1/schools/"
p =  {"school.operating" : "1", "2015.academics.program_available.assoc_or_bachelors" : "true", "2015.student.size__range" : "1..", "school.degrees_awarded.predominant__range" :  "1..3", "school.degrees_awarded.highest__range" : "2..4", "id" : "240444", "api_key" : key}

resp = requests.get(url=url_base, params=p)
data = resp.json()
print data
```

Comment: Hey chillin! It appears to work. I'm going to focus on binding the json data to the HTML file now... thank you so much for your patience. You've been a tremendous help. :)

Comment: No problem. If you have any questions in relation to the above, let me know and I can help if I know the answer. Good luck.